# User overriden java preferences(Windows factory ) XmlPreferencesFactory is not getting loaded

Tags: install4j

We are setting our preference factory in command line option as

-Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=...preferences.XMLPreferencesFactory (we are using our own preference factory implementation )

this is not working but in place of this  windows- preference factory is getting used in install4j. 
same is working for eclipse and with other installer tool.

Snippet

Class userNodeFromClassPackage;

Preferences.userNodeForPackage( userNodeFromClassPackage );

But this Preferences does not create xmlPreferencesFactory. It seems that already Preferences is invoked in install4j so it returns the windows Preferences. Please help how to set the -Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory variable so that our own PreferencesFactory(XMLPreferencesFactory) should be used in place of Windows Preferences.

Comment: Is this for the installer or for the launcher? If you pass this as a VM parameter, it should work in both cases, install4j does not set its own preferences factory.

Comment: This problem is with launcher. We tried with  passing the above as VM parameters. It does set the variable and when we there is changes in the app related to preferences then it does save in the preferences.xml but when I quit the application and then relaunch it , the default preference.xml is created and it replaces the old one. So user saved preferences are getting lost.

Comment: Try starting the app with -J-Dinstall4j.noLoggingFix=true from the command line. Then the preferences subsystem is not accessed at all. If this helps, add -Dinstall4j.noLoggingFix=true to the VM parameters in the launcher wizard.

Comment: Preferences did not work as suggested, it looks like Windows preferences has been picked in stead of xmlPreferences.

Comment: Preferences did not work as suggested, it looks like Windows preferences has been picked in stead of xmlPreferences.we also noticed PreferencesUtil class in install4j which also call preferences , we suspect this is creating the problem, but under javasoft we did not notice any node , but nodes are getting created in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ej-technologies\install4j\installations, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ej-technologies\exe4j\jvms\c:/program files (x86)/sitemanager/jre/bin/java.exe, , if we delete this and again run our app it again creates these nodes,

Comment: Yes, but those are created by the native part of the launcher, not by the Java part. With the VM parameter that I sent you the Java part of the launcher will not call the java.util.preferences classes.

Comment: We tried setting the  -J-Dinstall4j.noLoggingFix=true as a VM parameter and then launch our application. Now the preferences is not getting created at all unlike in earlier case it was getting created but getting overridden in the next launch. The property Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=...preferences.XMLPreferencesFactory is getting set but the XML preferences is not getting created.

Comment: Not sure how install4j could be responsible for this, the preferences subsystem is now not touched at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Installer main method of WinLauncher class internally calls InstallerUtil's disablePreferencesLogging which uses Preferences first, -J-Dinstall4j.noLoggingFix=true does not disabled this as Preferences in java has static method factory() which sets its value when class is loaded and instantiate it(WindowsPreferences, FilePreferences or Service bundle etc),

In your dev(eclipse) setup  this works as Preferences gets loaded when this is called from your code and your business logic might depend on this.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes this is working! Thanks! We were not able to locate WinLauncher and InstallerUtil.